# Incorrect first row in webscrape using R

Tags: html, r, csv, web-scraping

I have created a program in R to scrape a website. I am currently trying to change all 'NA' in my csv output to 'NO'.  I have been successful however my solution alters my first row which should be "Title" "Authors" Author "Affiliations" and so on. If I were to remove my script to change  the "NA" then the row is correct.

The code for this is below

```
library(rvest)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(stringr)
#for Fulltext to read pdf
####install.packages("pdftools")
library("pdftools")


#Getting the number of Page
getPageNumber <- function(URL) {
  print(URL)
  parsedDocument <- read_html(URL)
  results_per_page <- length(parsedDocument %>% html_nodes(".sr-list"))
  total_results <- parsedDocument %>%
    toString() %>%
    str_match(., 'num_results":"(.*?)"') %>% 
    .[,2] %>%
    as.integer()
  pageNumber <- tryCatch(ceiling(total_results / results_per_page), error = function(e) {1})
  return(pageNumber)
}


#Getting all articles based off of their DOI
getAllArticles <-function(URL){
  parsedDocument = read_html(URL)
  findLocationDiv <- html_nodes(parsedDocument,'div')
  foundClass <-  findLocationDiv[which(html_attr(findLocationDiv, "class") == "al-citation-list")]
  ArticleDOInumber = trimws(gsub(".*10.1093/dnares/","",html_text(foundClass)))
  DOImain <- "https://doi.org/10.1093/dnares/"
  fullDOI <- paste(DOImain, ArticleDOInumber, sep = "")
  return(fullDOI)
}


#Get Title of journals
Title <- function(parsedDocument) {
  Title <- parsedDocument %>%
    html_node(".article-title-main") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    gsub("\\r\\n\\s+", "", .) %>%
    trimws(.)
  Title <- ifelse(is.na(Title), "No", Title)
  return(Title)
}

#Getting Authors of Journals
Authors <- function(parsedDocument){
  Authors <- parsedDocument %>%
    html_node("a.linked-name") %>%
    html_text() %>%
  return(Authors)
}

#main function with input as parameter year
findURL <- function(year_chosen){
  if (year_chosen >= 1994) {
    noYearURL <- glue::glue("https://academic.oup.com/dnaresearch/search-results?rg_IssuePublicationDate=01%2F01%2F{year_chosen}%20TO%2012%2F31%2F{year_chosen}")
    pagesURl <- "&fl_SiteID=5275&page="
    URL <- paste(noYearURL, pagesURl, sep = "")
    # URL is working with parameter year_chosen
    firstPage <- getPageNumber(URL)
    if (firstPage == 5) {
      nextPage <- 0
      while (firstPage < nextPage | firstPage != nextPage) {
        firstPage <- nextPage
        URLwithPageNum <- paste(URL, firstPage-1, sep = "")
        nextPage <- getPageNumber(URLwithPageNum)
      }
    }
  DNAresearch <- data.frame()
    for (i in 1:firstPage) {
      URLallArticles <- getAllArticles(paste(URL, i, sep = ""))
      print(URLallArticles)
      for (j in 1:(length(URLallArticles))) {
        if(url.exists((URLallArticles[j]))){
          parsedDocument <- read_html(URLallArticles[j])
          paste(parsedDocument)
          
          #need work on getiing Full Text
          #allData <- data.frame("Full text"= fullText(parsedDocument),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

          #"Title" = Title(parsedDocument),"Authors" = Authors(parsedDocument),"Author Affiliations" = AuthorAffil(parsedDocument),"Corresponding  Authors" = CorrespondingAuthors(parsedDocument),"CoAuthor Email" = CoAuthorEmail(parsedDocument),"Publish Date" = PublicationDate(parsedDocument),"Abstract" = Abstract(parsedDocument),"Keywords" = Keywords(parsedDocument)
          allData <- data.frame("Title" = Title(parsedDocument),"Authors" = Authors(parsedDocument),"Author Affiliations" = AuthorAffil(parsedDocument),"Corresponding  Authors" = CorrespondingAuthors(parsedDocument),"CoAuthor Email" = CoAuthorEmail(parsedDocument),"Publish Date" = PublicationDate(parsedDocument),"Abstract" = Abstract(parsedDocument),"Keywords" = Keywords(parsedDocument),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
          
          #NA check to change it to NO
          allData <- ifelse(is.na.data.frame(allData), "No", allData)
          DNAresearch <- rbind(DNAresearch, allData)
        }
      }
    }
    write.csv(DNAresearch, "DNAresearch.csv", row.names = FALSE)
  } else {
    print("The Year you provide is out of range, this journal only contain articles from 1994 to present")
  }
}

##################### Main function test
findURL(2018)
```

The csv output is this
[image]

However it should be like this

[image]

Also if you could show how to fix the spacing in the csv for  example 'Author.Affiliation' to  -> 'Author Affiliation'

Comment: Take this line out `allData <- ifelse(is.na.data.frame(allData), "No", allData)`  and see if the problem continues.  It would be easier to read all of the data in, then change the NA to No immediately prior to writing the file.

Comment: Instead of copying all your code can you trim this down to only relevant code necessary to reproduce the issue that you are facing?

Comment: Your code produces an empty dataframe. Also, I am not certain of your logic in section `if (firstPage == 5.....` as firstPage is 18 for that year.

Comment: So the problem I am facing does not occur anymore when I remove the 'allData <- ifelse(is.na.data.frame(allData), "No", allData)'. But I need a command that changes 'NA' to 'No' which is why it is there

Comment: For 'if (firstPage == 5.....' I have that because in the first page of the articles the max pages it shows is 5

Comment: Also Ronak my program is a lot longer than this so I tried to reduce the program to only the main functions. If something is unclear than I am happy to explain

Comment: Once you have the final dataframe, you can then go column by column converting the NA to "No".

Comment: Dave2e I have been having a huge problem with my program. The csv file has stopped outputting and nothing now works.  Have u tested my program?