# Webscraping all text in an article in R

Tags: html, r, web, web-scraping

I am creating a webscraper where I am gathering the full text of an article. As so right now I have not been able to grab the html needed for the full text of the arrticle. The text should later be outputted onto a csv with the text  all in one row

My output is currently blank

My program is below:

```
library(rvest)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(stringr)
#for Fulltext to read pdf
####install.packages("pdftools")
library(pdftools)

fullText <- function(parsedDocument){
  fullText <- parsedDocument %>%
    html_nodes("a.article-body") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    return(fullText)
}

#main function with input as parameter year
testFullText <- function(DOIurl){
  parsedDocument <- read_html(DOIurl)
  DNAresearch <- data.frame()
  allData <- data.frame("Full Text" = fullText(parsedDocument), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  DNAresearch <-  rbind(DNAresearch, allData)
  write.csv(DNAresearch, "DNAresearch.csv", row.names = FALSE)
}
testFullText("https://doi.org/10.1093/dnares/dsm026")
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to download the pdf file before trying to extract the text from it.

Reading the html source it appears the pdf file link is stored in a "meta" tag.  From there you can either download the document or attempt to use the "pdftools" library on the document.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

#read webpage
DOIurl<- "https://doi.org/10.1093/dnares/dsm026"
page <-read_html(DOIurl)

#find the meta tag with pdf link and extract the content
pdffile <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath='.//meta[@name="citation_pdf_url"]') %>% html_attr("content")

#download the document
download.file(pdffile, "Internetpaper.pdf")
```

If you are looking for only certain section of the paper, then it may make sense to extract that information directly from the webpage instead of downloading the document.
Also see this questions [Incorrect first row in webscrape using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66847428/incorrect-first-row-in-webscrape-using-r) and other questions from this user, as it appears you are working on similar problems.
That would be good for another question with a better define goals instead of give me everything.

Comment: I'm trying  to write the full text out into a csv file instead of making a new pdf file

Comment: I would like to add, I posted a similar question and this is when I tried using pdfTools but never got help on the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66879402/r-webscraper-is-not-outputting-pdf-text-in-one-row

Comment: I’m not familiar with pdftools so can’t help with that.  Having the file in hand is an important first step.  I suggest deleting the previous question and asking a new one on extracting from the file

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get the text of the article with the following code :

```
library(RDCOMClient)

url <- "https://doi.org/10.1093/dnares/dsm026"
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(5)
doc <- IEApp$Document()
web_Obj <- doc$getElementByID("ContentTab")
article_Text <- web_Obj$innerText()
```